# Typescript I cannot understand this type syntax

Tags: angular, typescript

I cannot understand this syntax as a type in Angular

```
sequencedEventItems: { [order: number]: Event }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax mean your are declaring an object, its key are going to be numbers and its value are going to be Event.:

```js
{
   0: SomeEvent
}
```

Please note that even though the object's keys are number, this is not an array. it's an object.

Answer (score 2):

That means that `sequencedEventItems` is a dictionary (object), whereby the properties(keys) are of `number` type, and the values are of `Event` type.

You may read more about TypeScript interfaces and Indexable Types over [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types).

That being said, that is how the above object might look like

```
{
  sequencedEventItems: {
    1: EventA,
    2: EventB,
    3: EventC,
    // others
  },
}
```